# .NET equivalent of StrCmpLogicalW

Tags: c#, string, sorting, .net-3.5

What is the managed equivalent of [`StrCmpLogicalW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

---

Nieve string sorting rules would sort a list as:

- Window 1
- Window 10
- Window 12
- Window 2
- Window 27
- Window 3
- Window 4
- Window 5

Starting with **Windows XP**, Microsoft introduced [`StrCmpLogicalW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - to sort strings in a way people expect:

- Window 1
- Window 2
- Window 3
- Window 4
- Window 5
- Window 10
- Window 12
- Window 27

> **Nitpicker's Corner:** [Some people find this sort order confusing.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/18/134051.aspx#135042) They're not part of this conversation.

Starting with **Windows 7**, Microsoft brought the functionality of StrCmpLogicalW into [`CompareString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the new `SORT_DIGITSASNUMBERS` flag:

> **Windows 7:** Treat digits as numbers during sorting, for example, sort "2" before "10".

Without resorting to P/Invoke (obviously), what the the .NET framework equivalent of sorting strings naturally?